# knowing the basic rules or ways of doing something

Tags: vocabulary

I am wondering when you want to say the following, what/ how  you say it?

To know the basic principle or rules of doing something

For instance, he must know the basic rules of the way of doing research to be able to publish it.

Please feel free to ask any question, as the question might not be clear enough.

Thanks

Comment: "the basic rules of the way of doing research" is redundant: the basic rules of (doing) research would be just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can say the newbie must *familiarise* himself with the job. Alternatively, newcomers are usually expected to *[learn the ropes](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/49488/10972)*.

They both convey the idea the person is expected to pick up the basics before any progression can take place.